# Map::operator[] always requires a default constructor

Tags: c++, dictionary, default-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class x{
  public:
  string s;
  //x(){cout<<"default"<<endl;}
  x(string s=""):s(s){cout<<"mine"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
  map<int,x> m;
  m.insert(pair<int,x>(1,x("me")));
  cout<<m[1].s<<endl;
}
```

*I understand that map::operator[] requires default cst for when element is not present, but*

**m[1] gives error without default cst for class x in apple clang, even though the element for m[1] is already present. WHY?**

Comment: That's how static checking works.

Comment: How may the compiler know about the existing element?

Comment: Use `at`: `m.at(1).s` doesn't require default ctor

Comment: In order to determine at compile-time that the object exists, the compiler would need to execute the program, but it's impossible to execute the program without first compiling it.

Comment: @fas is map::at c++11 feature?

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly it is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at. Note that `std::map::at` throws if no such key present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that map::operator[] requires default cst for when element is not present, [...]

That's not quite correct.

`map::operator[]` always requires a default constructor because the element might not be present. Whether it actually is present is not that relevant, because whether a `map<T>` has a `operator[]` is decided at compile time already.